# Сдвиг строки в PHPStorm влево вправо независимо где находится курсор

Tags: phpstorm, netbeans

В netBeans сочетания клавиш shift+alt+(left и right) сдвинет строку влево и вправо не зависимо где находится курсор в этой строке - в начале, в середине или в конце строки.  Очень удобно. В PHPStorm не нашел  и приходится постоянно делать несколько манипуляций
1 - нажать home, перейти в начало строки
2 - и потом с помощью tub или shift+tub влево/вправо двигаешь
Вообщем не удобно. Кто нибудь знает, как решить эту задачу?

## Как вариант

сменил keymap на netBeans в setting, теперь у меня все сочетании клавиш, как netBeans, как будто не переходил, только дизайн другой.

Answer (score 0):

В настройках `Keymap -> Next tab && Prev Tab` поменяй на какие удобно